# Server crash: Node.js socket.io asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have code like:

```
 if(players[j].socket){
  players[j].socket.emit("bla");
  players[j].socket.emit("bla");
 }
```

second emit crash server because:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of null
```

But how its possible that second emit crash server? In first emit socket isn't null, but in second is? I think that for second emit players[j] has other value, cause players array have been changed.

But how you can see in my code i don't do anything with players array. Is possible that some other asynchronous code changed players array? Shouldn't be javascript synchronous?

Is possible in my code that players[j] in my first line is different as in second line?

Edit: some players have socket property null, cause they are bots.

Edit2: also this problem began after I implemented bots.

Comment: How/where do you construct your `players`? Clearly, by the time the second line is executed `players[j]` is null.

Comment: Did you close the socket in any part of your code?

Comment: Just add some break point to debug. `console.log(j, players[j].socket); players[j].socket.emit("bla"); console.log(j, players[j].socket); players[j].socket.emit("bla");`

Comment: I've run into this type of thing... Bear in mind that Javascript doesn't deep copy objects.. ;)  This could mean that when you're adding connections to the array, you're not actually grabbing the whole thing.  I've switched over to querying the web socket class for current connections and I'm adding an _id to them when they start up so that I can tell one from the other.

Comment: These kind of bugs are really easy to debug and test, please console log your j , and players[j], and players before that line, and you will see everything and from there will see which one is being 'cleared'. Then reverse through code and find it

Comment: players[j].socket is null in second line probably because its bot that has null value by default

Comment: Moshe Shmukler: you mean players[j].socket is null?

Comment: i already changed my code in server (i chache players[j]). my question is if its possible that players[j].socket in first line is different as in second line. because if im right it shouldnt be possible

Comment: If you have bots and players, why not cache them in two different places. I assume something weird happens with bot/player being added or removed. Btw I would recommend you to use socketRooms instead of you saving them in arrays. You will be able to emit to the whole group and have the ability to horizontal scale in the future.